# No comprendo el argumento de lambda porque no reconozco la función a aplicar

Tags: lambda

Buen dia!
Recién estoy comprendiendo como se usa lambda (Python) y sé que después de los 2 puntos sigue la expresión o formula a aplicar a cada item, pero como sería este código que encontré, que no lo comprendo? en lugar de una fórmula hay un par de items.....o sería otra cosa? Gracias!!

```
return sorted(nums, key=lambda x: (count[x], -x))
```

Comment: Sería bueno que facilitaras el código donde está ese return para saber qué pudiera estar pasando.

Comment: La función sorted  es de Python. Tienes toda  la información en la documentación https://docs.python.org/es/3/ buscas sorted

Answer (score 0):

Un `lambda` no es más que una función como cualquier otra, solo que se la crea "al vuelo" y muere una vez ya utilizada, se las suele llamar funciones anónimas por que justamente no tienen un nombre asignado. En tu ejemplo:

```
lambda x: (count[x], -x)
```

es equivalente a

```
def mi_funcion(x):
    return (count[x], -x)
```

De hecho, tranquilamente podrías usar `mi_funcion()`:

```
return sorted(nums, key=mi_funcion)
```

En el caso de `sorted()` la función `key` se usa para generar un "clave" por la cual se ordenará. Por lo que se entiende de tu ejemplo, el orden estaría dado por el valor en `count`, otro array, de cada elemento de elemento de `nums` y el elemento de `nums` en orden descendente.